# JSON.NET fails to parse long integer value

Tags: json.net, deserialization, long-integer

i have some json data like this:

```
{
    'vehicles':{
    ...
    },
    'arenaUniqueID':214197923159382012L,
    'common':{
    ...
    },
    'players':{
    ...
    },
    'personal':{
    ...
    }
}
```

and class for deserializing this data

```
public class UnPickledData
{
    public Dictionary<int, Vehicle> vehicles { get; set; }        
    public long arenaUniqueID { get; set; }
    public Common common { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Player> players { get; set; }
    public Personal personal { get; set; }
}
```

during deserialization program throws exception:

> After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: L. Path
>   arenaUniqueID', line 1, position 51810.

i tried to write own custom JSonConverter for that property:
changed class:

```
public class UnPickledData
{
    public Dictionary<int, Vehicle> vehicles { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomLongConverter))]
    public Int64 arenaUniqueID { get; set; }
    public Common common { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Player> players { get; set; }
    public Personal personal { get; set; }
}
```

converter code:

```
class CustomLongConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(long);
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return Int64.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());           
    }
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

but this exception still happens.

what i'm doing wrong and howto fix this?

p.s. using Newtonsoft.JSON v5.0.5.16108/.Net FW 3.5/VS 2010

Answer (score 3):

The L after the number isn't valid JSON.

Comment: But it's valid c\c++ long integer value (program that fills json with data coded using c++ and python).  Is there any way to fix this error without reparsing json before deserializing?

Comment: @Pavel You should fix the serializing program not to send the "L".  As James said, having an "L" suffix on a number is not part of the [JSON specification](http://json.org/), therefore you cannot expect a standard JSON parser to accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not do this (the program that serializes the data is not written by me and I don't have the opportunity to fix it), so I'll have to reinvent the wheel :(